# Does normalization of a random vector, destroy uniformity?

Tags: random-variables

If I have a random vector in R<sup>n</sup> that has a uniform distribution in the domain [a,b]<sup>n</sup>, a<0, b>0. Is uniformity lost or preserved (in the unit sphere) if I normalize the vector (using the euclidean norm)?

Comment: Let $a=5,\ b=10$. Then, if $Y=\frac{X}{\|X\|}$, $P\{Y_1<0\}=0$

Comment: I have altered the requirement on a and b

Comment: Consider $n = 1, a = -1, b = 2.$ Denote the random variable uniformly distributed on $[-1,2]$ by $X.$ Since $P(X=0) = 0,$ we can define the random variable $Y = \frac{X}{\|X\|}.$ Now, observe that $P(Y = -1) = \frac13$ and $P(Y = 1) = \frac23.$ So normalization destroys uniformity.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli's counterexample still holds, only slightly modified (pondering it would have been a more fruitful reaction).